# how to check net connection speed

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, network-interface

I want to show internet connection speed in a label with the help of timer. I wrote :

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim myNA() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces

    lblConnectStatus.Text = "NET CONNECTION SPEED : " & myNA(0).Speed / 1000000 & " Kbps."
End Sub
```

This shows 7.2 Kbps. in the label and remains the same all time.
Can anyone help..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you think that the speed of the interface should change over time. If I have a GBit NIC which is connected to a GBit switch it will have a "speed" of 1 GBit all the time. If your Nic is connected to a router and the router is connected "to the internet", you read the speed of the conection to the router of course and not the speed of the routers conection to the internet.

Comment: When i check net speed in my modem statistics it's graph shows large fluctuation, then why not my code ??

Comment: Thanks @John Saunders for editing my title.

Comment: @Dev: Dont mix the "speed" of the connection with the speed of data-transfer. Say you have a highway with a speed limit of 50. Then your highway's "speed" is 50. That doesnt mean that any car will travel at this speed!

Comment: What you're measuring is the capacity of your network connection to the _next device_ which might be a router/modem/switch depending on how your connection is set up.  If you're pulling data from the internet, you would need to find the slowest connection in the chain between you and the server in question - even then, you'd only know the maximum capacity for the connection to that server. The only way to do what you want is download something from a fast, known good server and time how long it takes to transfer

Comment: Why use quotes on the word speed? There are two distinct metrics being discussed here -- speed and throughput. Throughput is what is being asked about. Why not simply explain the difference? Speed is more akin to a limit and throughput is the observed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have something on the internet that you can actually download and use math to determine how long it takes.

There are tones of ways you can do this but the more lower level your function (to get the data) is, the more accurate it will be. IE, if you used something like the Browser control, your result would be low, if even messureable, since you wouldn't know the exact number of bytes you downloaded.

The simplest might be to use something like `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile()` (simple, but not the MOST accurate) to download a known large file, like a PDF, and time it using somehting like this:

```
dim dStart as DateTime = Now
...Download Code
dim ts as TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(dStart)
```

Then you can take the size of your file, and the time it took to download, to determine the speed.

Comment: BTW, I like using a WebService where I can ask for the number of byte I want, then time how long that takes. Then I can zero in on how many bytes I can download in 1 second, and come up with a pretty accurate speed.  But, this does require you to build and host your own Web Service.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following controls:

- Webbrowser1
- Button1,text=" Get internet speed"
- Label1,text="0 Bytes per second"

Paste this code in your program

```
  Dim t a datetime
 Sub bclk handles button1.click
  Webbrowser1.navigate("stackoverflow.com")
  T= now
 End sub

 Sub wbdoccomplete handles   webbeowser1.documentcomplete
  Dim tspan =now.subtract(t)
  Dim speed as double = (webbrowser1.                        Documenttext.length/tspan.totalseconds)
  Label1.text = speed & " Bytes per second"
End sub
```

Comment: Using a TIMER to MEASURE time? Big no-go. And interval=1 for timer doesnt make sense anyway, since the minimum resolution is somewhere near 15-16 ms (or worse), but never "exact".

Comment: You still use a `Timer` to MEASURE time, which makes no sense, you still have an unrealistic interval, you rely on an event that is fired in the UI thread while you use a blocking call at the same time, you do not measure download speed alone, but also dns resolution etc ...

Comment: The above all applies, but also, this is still an inaccurate measure, as it does not consider the headers.